# Moving VMware OS image as primary OS on a system

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

How can you take a VMware image and place it onto other hardware systems as the default OS? I want to do this with my Ubuntu VM's

Comment: I want to do the same think. I want to ask you that did the answer worked for you? Did you Ubuntu VM was successfully installed in other system as default OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VMWare's VMWare Converter

Here's a link to some documentaiton from VMWare's site

http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You could always use an imaging tool such as clonezilla, make an image, and restore it to the target drive i think. At worst it would requite you to repair grub